# Substring in select statement in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I'm trying to `select` a **substring** of column, i.e. `select substring(description, 1, 200) from category where id=1`

Is it possible to have a substring function within a select statement in JPQL/JPA 2? If yes, how? If no, are there any alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a scalar expression for this:  **SUBSTRING(string, start, end)**

I believe this is allowed in the SELECT clause in JPA 2.0, but not in JPA 1.0.